# How to run Phonegap/Cordova plus a basic plugin on PhoneGap Developer?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So I'm trying to run a sample application with plugin on my android cellphone with PhoneGap Developer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app

When I run the project via latest PhoneGap Desktop or cli `phonegap serve`, the plugin code won't execute, I get this on the server log:

> 200 /__api__/appzip
>
> 200 /socket.io/socket.io.js
>
> 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1435046239827-0
>
> 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1435046241593-1&sid=AAq7UmoObLTv1QeKAAAA
>
> 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1435046241639-2&sid=AAq7UmoObLTv1QeKAAAA`

When I run the same project with cordova cli `cordova serve`, I get an error on PhoneGap Developer "Unable to download archive from server, and the console has this:

> 404 /__api__/appzip

When I use `cordova run` the app and plugin code will run correctly on my PC android emulator.

I already tried creating the project with PhoneGap Desktop and command line.

The plugins I'm trying to test are very basic

1. https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello
2. https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

Any ideas?

Comment: phonegap developer app can only execute the core plugins

Comment: @jcesarmobile It's been a while but basically that is the answer